# English translation of Karl Barth's Fürchte dich nicht (1949)

Tags: resource-request, translation, sermon, karl-barth

Does anyone know where I can find an English translation of a book containing Karl Barth's sermons from 1934 to 1948, [*Fürchte dich nicht! - Predigten aus den Jahren 1934 bis 1948*](https://archive.org/details/frchtedichnichtp0000bart/page/n5/mode/2up), published in 1949?

Comment: When I would google this question, I'd be dropped into "bach-cantatas" but under "https://archive.org/details/frchtedichnichtp0000bart/mode/2up?view=theater" I could open a copy of the book from The Library of the Claremont School of Theology. This copy is in the original German (I wish I knew German so I wouldn't be dependent on someone else's translation)! My question is whether this text has ever been translated into English. Because of its popularity, I have to believe there's a translation somewhere out there.

Comment: @depperm I think Ed Huff was asking about a book by Karl Barth, not the [cantata by J.S. Bach with the same title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrchte_dich_nicht,_BWV_228) which because the latter is much more popular, it dominated the first page of the Google search result.

Comment: @edhuff I don't think this book has been translated into English yet, maybe since it's less popular than his magnum opus Church Dogmatics and his commentary on the Romans.  But I have emailed the [Center for Barth Studies at Princeton Theological Seminary](https://barth.ptsem.edu/translators-seminar/) in case they have more information.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the book by Barth which I can find on archive.org but only in German.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be anxious to find out if they are able to locate an English translation!

Comment: I'm assuming that the Princeton Center probably came up empty on finding a translation.

Comment: The Center fo Barth Studies got back to me with the following:    Dear Ed,
 
Unfortunately, Barth’s sermon “Fürchte dich nicht!” from 1949 has not been translated into English, only Japanese from the original German: http://barthresearch.org/barth/cgi-bin/resultaat.cgi?searchid=6013&taal=Eng&zoekmet=titel&zoeknaar=boek&searchvalue=%22F%FCrchte%20dich%20nicht%22